# How to properly define my authenticate routes in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

I am new to laravel and i am trying to define my routes.And the logic is "/" routing to "/login" if the user is not authenticated and "/login" routing to login view blade.Down below are the routes.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});

Route::get('login', function (){

    return view('auth/login');

});

Route::get('register', function (){

    if(Auth::check()){

        return view('home');

    }else{

        return view('auth/register');
    }

});

Route::get('/', function () {

    if(Auth::check()){

        return view('home');

    }else{

        return redirect('/login');

    }
});




Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

But i am keep getting this error "Route [login] not defined." and i can't see the problem.

Comment: You might want to read through the documentation about authentication [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication). Laravel provides all this functionality out of the box for you.

Comment: i know but they are using a different routes logic

Comment: How so? It literally provides all the routes you've defined above and handles all the redirection. I think you may be reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add `Auth::routes()` in a fresh laravel 7 installation shows this on `artisan route:list`:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm       | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | password/confirm       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web          |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

You should then avoid defining the same routes again with a different implementation. Let Laravel doing the work for you.
As you can see, there are also already middlewares applied to these predefined routes. `web` in this scenario is not a middleware itself but a middleware group defined at `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Please see below for more info about middleware groups.

If you want to kind of "remove" the / -route from your project you can use a redirect route.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#redirect-routes

So your route file should, after all, look like this:

```php
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});

// this will let laravel automatically redirect again if already logged in
Route::permanentRedirect('/', '/login');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

The automation which will redirect you towards the `/home`-route is an interaction between `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` and `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`.

Within the latter, you have an attribute defining your `HOME`

```php
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';
```

If you have later more routes which should apply the `auth()`-middleware you have three ways to do that (or probably 4):

Please compare the following examples to this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#middleware-groups

As a general thing maybe a bit hard to see in the beginning, there is no difference between a controller route and those which use a closure function. The methods which can be used are the same for both implementations. Only the handling of the route within the application will be different.

For a single route which is needing a middleware, just add it to the end.
This is applicable for controller routes as well as for closure routes.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware('web');
// ^^^^ is as possible as:
Route::get('/', 'Controller@Method')->middleware('web');
```

For multiple routes using the same middleware use the middleware method.
It is possible to use multiple middlewares assigned as parts of the array.

```php
Route::middleware(['web', 'subscribed'])->group(function () {
    //
});
```

If you still need more customization use the `group()`-method directly.
Here you can define not only middleware but also for example a prefix for all enclosed routes

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix'=>'admin'], function () {
    //
});
```

As the last option, you can add any middleware you want to either an existing middleware group or add your own middleware group within `app/Http/Kernel.php?`. But this will cause pretty strong integration hard to build an exception for if you want to go off track because everything within a middleware group is used all the time for every route this group is applied to.

Please do not mix Route groups with middleware groups as these are different things.

All of these examples were found in the docs for the 7th version, so they should be applicable also for your case.

Comment: You should mention that Closure routes are a bad practice because of readability, but above all because Closures cannot be efficiently serialized for routes caching on production mode https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#route-caching

Comment: I tried what you said and i have another problem now.I am using wamp and my project is inl ocalhost/PROJECTNAME/ and when i use Route::permanentRedirect('/', '/login'); the app is goint to localhost/login not to logalhost/PROJECTNAME/public/login

Comment: OK, there are two types of requests. First, there is the one made from "outside". That could be via postman or simply type into your browser. Then you have to use of course ```locahost/PROJECTNAME````. On the other hand, you have URLs created by larave itself living inside your deliverd views. Those URLs should be full qualified and not relative. make sure to configure your ```.env```-file and ```config/app.php``` file properly with the right URL so that generated URLs will point to the correct, full qualified URL.

Comment: the URL was ok on env. Anyway i changed to  artisan server and it's all ok

Comment: Please make sure to eventually configure your app properly because of a security risk you will create running your app not within the document root of a web server/ host if you are not on your local machine.
Please see the docs for the proper configuration: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#web-server-configuration